# jQuery slider not working on production server but working on local server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, google-chrome-devtools, revolution-slider

I have a problem with a slider (Revolution Slider) displaying on a website on a production server. I have a slider that I am playing around with and it works perfectly on my local machine but when I upload to a production server, it's not displaying the slide.

I have attached a screenshot of the inspect element and the li element is highlighted purple for some reason on production. [image]

It is not highlighted purple on my local machine so it seems like something is wrong with the loading of this element in production and it has to do with the possible order of the JavaScript files. I am trying to learn how to debug this issue with the Event Listeners tab of Chrome but I don't know enough to start debugging this issue (I have read and Googled and still don't know how to isolate the issue).

How can I debug what's happening to this slider slide and why it's not showing up on production when it's showing up on my local machine environment just fine?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: That's the problem, I am getting no errors in the console. Normally I can follow the console errors and figure it out. No errors on this one.

Comment: @thenextmogul I suspect if the there was an ordering issue, you'd be getting some reference exceptions in your Console. You could use the `Script First Statement` Event Listener Breakpoints to step through. You may also want to check the CSS styles on the right-hand panel in Elements to see if something is getting hidden there. Not too sure of best starting point, especially without seeing any code.